# Did any superpower or great power ever did anything covert or extra-diplomatic in the Republic of India?

Tags: india

A substantial number of people in China have an opinion that the [USA and the West tried to interfere with Chinese politics](https://www.reuters.com/world/china/china-draws-up-list-100-instances-us-interference-hong-kong-2021-09-24/). It is widely agreed upon in Turkey that [USA was instrumental in 2016 coup](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/03/world/europe/turkey-coup-erdogan-fethullah-gulen-united-states.html) in Turkey. Ex-PM of Pakistan said that USA was instrumental in de-seating him in this year.

- [The long history of the U.S. interfering with elections elsewhere](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2016/10/13/the-long-history-of-the-u-s-interfering-with-elections-elsewhere/)
- [America’s role in Latin American regime change](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/americas/america-s-role-in-latin-american-regime-change/1404970)
- [The U.S. tried to change other countries’ governments 72 times during the Cold War](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2016/12/23/the-cia-says-russia-hacked-the-u-s-election-here-are-6-things-to-learn-from-cold-war-attempts-to-change-regimes/)

The [**USSR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_involvement_in_regime_change#:%7E:text=Soviet%20involvement%20in%20regime%20change%20entailed%20both%20overt%20and%20covert,Mongolia%20into%20a%20satellite%20state.) and [**Russia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_involvement_in_regime_change) have a long history of interfering in other country's internal affairs.

**France** has a long [history of interference in Africa](https://dailytrust.com/france-africas-unwanted-guest).

**I don't see the name of India in the list.**

- Is it because India is too dear and respected? If YES, why???

or,

- Is it because India is not an important country to interfere in? (I doubt so!)

or,

- Is it because India is too loyal? (I doubt so!)

or,

- Is it because Indians have too much influence in the US and Russian or French politics and administration? (I think, this is what happening right now. But, what about, say, 30-40 years ago?)

Can anyone come up with a satisfactory explanation?

Comment: The title and body of your question don't add up. Is this about any super power or the us?

Comment: No, it's not "widely agreed upon that USA was instrumental in 2016 coup in Turkey". It is or at least [it was](https://www.reuters.com/article/turkey-security-usa-int-idUSKBN2A41NF) the Turkish gov't position, but that doesn't make it "widely agreed"; "The U.S. State Department said the accusation was “wholly false.”"

Comment: @Fizz, *The U.S. State Department said the accusation was “wholly false.* --- Yeah, like Saddam had WMD!! Like Russia never used Novichok!! Like France never assassinated any African leader!!

Comment: Turkey's government takes the extreme position that granting asylum to someone is the same as supporting them achieve their goals. so e.g. they say the US supported the coup because  Fethullah Gulen lives in the USA. They say that Finland and Sweden support terrorists against Turkey because they grant asylum to some Kurds etc.

Comment: @Fizz, Like Snowden living in Russia, or, Assange staying in Ecuadorian embassy.

Comment: Do note that Pakistan is in the US sphere of influence so they may be doing so via proxy, not unlike how the US uses the KSA in the middle East.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because the Indian government has not yet found it politically convenient to raise such accusations. Your standard for what it means that it is "widely agreed upon that USA was instrumental" in one thing or another is basically just that.

So, the question is ultimately why the Indian government is less inclined to scapegoat the USA. Reasons can be varied, but I suspect that closer economic ties, like e.g. number of work visas granted to Indians, as well as companies outsourcing to India might have something to do with that.

And while they might not have complained about any alleged covert actions... as one Indian newspaper [puts it](https://theprint.in/opinion/youre-wrong-to-think-hindu-right-turned-anti-america-its-american-left-thats-anti-india/903311/)

> Manmohan Singh, openly complained on American TV that American NGOs were supporting and funding protests against the development of nuclear power plants in India. An American animal rights NGO used the existence of a law to prevent cruelty to animals, to fund litigation that resulted in the ban of jallikattu, an Indian version of bullfighting. This ban was widely opposed by many sections of Indians, including regional political parties that were not in Modi’s camp. Such egregious interference by the patronising and sanctimonious American NGOs in the affairs of India has been a source of great disappointment for many Indians, not just for Manmohan Singh.

By the way, if India were to apply the [standards](https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20220522-turkey-s-erdogan-sets-conditions-for-finland-sweden-s-nato-bids) that Turkey applies to such accusations, they could easily accuse the US of supporting terrorism against India, via Pakistan. It seems rather obvious that the Turkish government perceive their NATO membership (and thus veto vote therein) as a hard bargaining chip, allowing them to make maximalist demands from the West. It's much less clear what India's bargaining strength would rest on, when they e.g. have to rely on the US at the UNSC and they are often opposed by China in that venue, [according](https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/china-blocks-us-india-move-to-list-pakistani-terrorist-in-united-nations-security-council-3074811) to the Indian press. Likewise, besides the domestic politics, a closer relationship with China allows at least a section of the Pakistani political spectrum to think they can forego US friendship. One can read in the Indian press about the historically good & important India-Russia relationship, but Russia doesn't have the kind of economic might that China has nowadays, to give the kind of hope of supplanting the US, economically.

Comment: *widely agreed upon* --- in Turkey, not in NATO or EU.

Comment: *Maybe because the Indian government has not yet found it politically convenient to raise such accusations.* --- Or may be those powers never tried such thing in India coz India is the #1 buyer of arms in the world.

Comment: So, raising complain of *interference* means *scapegoating* to you!! This means, those powers never interfered in other country's affairs, especially regime-changes, and victims were just complaining because they were expecting something from those powers and those powers were not ready to give them.

Comment: *It's much less clear what India's bargaining strength would rest on.* --- if you say so, its very clear. India is the largest buyer of arms in the world. India is the largest customer of Israeli and Russian (and probably also French arms). India is 10th largest buyer of US arms. US large corporations have huge investments in India.

Comment: However, the question remains --- this is not a current trend. I never heard anything about India since the 1980's.

Answer (score 0):

Note: recent edits made to clarify the meaning of the question invalidate the following answer. This answer was posted when the question just asked about interference, without specifying that it had to be covert or extradiplomatic.

---

Let's set aside whether the assertions in the question about the involvement of the United States in the coup attempt in Turkey or the ouster of the Pakistani Prime Minister are correct. The question gives various examples of interference, including a list given by the Chinese government, which in turn includes items such as the expression of support for a pro-democracy newspaper in Hong Kong and criticism of China's actions therein as oppressive. If this is the standard that the question uses, it is fairly obvious that the USA and other powerful countries have interfered in Indian politics:

For instance, US current president Joe Biden [criticized the India government for its "restrictions on dissent" in Kashmir, suggesting that the Indian government should change its policy to restore the rights of its residents, while also criticizing laws such as the Citizenship Amendment Act.](https://joebiden.com/muslimamerica/)

> In Kashmir, the Indian government should take all necessary steps to restore rights for all the people of Kashmir.  Restrictions on dissent, such as preventing peaceful protests or shutting or slowing down the Internet, weaken democracy. Joe Biden has been disappointed by the measures that the government of India has taken with the implementation and aftermath of the National Register of Citizens in Assam and the passage of the Citizenship Amendment Act into law.

Perhaps more substantively, when India refused to export a particular drug, [former US president Donald Trump said that there would be "retaliation."](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-52196730)

> The same day, speaking at a White House press briefing, Mr Trump said he did not "like" India's decision to ban the export of the drug. "But of course, there may be retaliation," he said. "Why wouldn't there be?"

India later retracted the ban.

Former president Bill Clinton also tried to influence Indian policy. [Per Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93United_States_relations?wprov=sfla1)

> Clinton simultaneously pressured India to liberalize its economy while criticizing New Delhi on human rights and nuclear issues

Comment: @user366312 Then you should perhaps not have provided the examples given by China in your question.

Comment: Your examples are what you would apparently characterize as "diplomatic pressures," such as the US criticizing China for its actions in Hong Kong or supporting a pro-democracy newspaper. One would naturally assume that you would be satisfied by similar examples for India.

Comment: @user366312 Undoubtedly you would be satisfied by those too. I could point out that China actually invaded India militarily at least twice, for instance.

Comment: If you meant only regime changes or attempted regime changes, then why did you give an example of interference by the US in China that was not a regime change? You can't expect answerers to read your mind. If you had asked about regime change specifically, obviously my answer would have been different.

Comment: @user366312 - Well, OK. If you believe that to be true, and you only meant to ask about regime change and not any type of interference, then it seems like it would have made more sense to (a) ask about regime change from the beginning, and (b) not have your example of US interference in China be an article that, by your standards, apparently does not describe interference at all. You can hardly fault me for answering the question the way you *actually asked it*.

Comment: @user366312 - An answer that accuses three US presidents of interfering in India's politics must be pro-US by your standards, I suppose. Whereas I suppose that your arguments that the US has never done it are "against the USA." Please, tell me more....